# Git ignore MR files that got in by accident, best approach?

Tags: git, gitlab

I, by accident, added 3 files to an MR that shouldn't have been included and I now need to ignore these changes. I'm not sure what is the best course of action here.

What is the best approach to ignore those files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git rm --cached <your_file>` to remove the file from being tracked by git. If you then push those change in a commit, it will remove it from the repository.

Comment: Thanks ill try this! Cheers

Comment: If you don't amend the commit and force push, the files will still be within the project history (and repository), but will not show up after this commit anymore. It depends on the details if this is the best(TM) solution. I would not mind to do history editing if those are small files with harmless content. But if those files are huge, history editing might be worth.

Comment: If he's already pushed the original commit to the repository, he won't have to amend and force push. He'd be untracking the files which git will mark as deletions which he can then commit and push without needing to force.

Comment: This will remove the file though, no? I dont want remove the existing version of the file, i just dont want it to have my change applied.

Comment: If you just want to revert changes to a particular file that was pushed in a branch, you can revert that commit by doing a `git reset --soft @~1`. That will revert the last commit you did.

You can then do a `git checkout <filename>` on the files you no longer want the changes of to reset them.

Then it's a case of just committing as usual and pushing with a `--force-with-lease`. I hope that makes sense as you're fairly new to git.

Comment: Problem is ive done quite a few commits since, as i didn't notice the error, and if i jump back to the given commit/push where the faulty changes were added, there will be a lot of other files there not up-to-date as well.

Comment: Just see how many commits back the issue was added. Then do the above `git reset --soft @~<number of commits>`, that will allow you to remove the issue whilst also keeping the existing changes you have. You'll lost the history when you force commit, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: another way beside the soft reset is to do an interactive rebase (git rebase -i head~n , n: how many commits back is your change), then edit that commit by removing the files then amend  and continue rebase, this way you maintain the rest of your commits not just the changes..